# Get a list result from another list and a property

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following 3 (simplified) model classes, each of which contains a collection of the other:

```
Group.CollectionOfPermissions
Group.CollectionOfUsers
User.CollectionOfGroups
User.CollectionOfPermissions
Permission.CollectionOfGroups
Permission.CollectionOfUsers
```

I have a View that is based off a single User.ID, and I want to be able to return the effective permissions for said user.

The effective permissions are based off:

1. The individual users' permissions, which is simply the User.CollectionOfPermissions property.
2. The derived permissions of the groups that the user is a part of. That is, for every Group to which the User belongs to, I need to grab those Permissions as well.

Number 1 is obviously as simple as referencing the collection property.
Number 2 is where I'm having a bit more trouble with a LINQ selection.

I could write a stored proc along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM PERMISSIONS P WHERE P.ID IN
(SELECT PERMISSION_ID FROM PERMISSION_GROUP_REF PGR WHERE PGR.GROUP_ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM GROUPS G WHERE G.ID IN 
(SELECT GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_USER_REF GUR WHERE GUR.USER_ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID = @USERID))))
```

But I'd much rather keep this in line with the rest of the project and continue to use LINQ, especially since I want to avoid directly querying the reference tables in code (given that the collections already exist as class properties). How would I approach this kind of LINQ query?

Edit: This is using Entity Framework 6 with Razor 3

Comment: What o/rm technology are you using? Entity Framework? What version?

Comment: @IainGalloway Will edit in details, good call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Users.Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
     .SelectMany(u => u.CollectionOfPermissions)
     .Select (cp=>cp.Permission) // you might need to do this too
     .Union(Users.Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                 .SelectMany(u => u.CollectionOfGroups)
                 .SelectMany(cg => cg.Permission))
```

May be something like this.

EDIT: For reference, this produces the following SQL (slightly different column names in my test rig):-

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [UnionAll1].[Permission_Id] AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Permission_Id] AS [Permission_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[PermissionPersons] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Person_Id]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent3].[Permission_Id] AS [Permission_Id]
        FROM  [dbo].[PersonGroups] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PermissionGroups] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Group_Id] = [Extent3].[Group_Id]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent2].[Person_Id]) AS [UnionAll1]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

On another thought, why not query through `Permission` entity all together?

```
context.Permissions.Where(p=>
                           p.Groups.Any(gr=>gr.Users.Any(u=>u.UserId == userId)) 
                           || p.Users.Any(u=>u.UserId == userId))
                   .Distinct()
```

Comment: Tidied the formatting a bit so I can read it, hope you don't mind. I suspect the second last extension method invocation there needs to also be "SelectMany"

Comment: I think for my needs, I can get rid of that 3rd line of of the LINQ query, but I need to test a bit more. This looks to be the right path though, I will update again later when I can play around with this a bit more. Thanks for the initial step in the right direction, I hope!

Comment: I like that last solution even better, as it starts from the actual Permissions set as opposed to querying down to it.

Comment: @JN Web: If you really care a lot, you should try both and profile. SelectMany does a JOIN, while Any will use WHERE EXISTS. Which is more performant will depend on your specific situation.

Comment: @IainGalloway I'll have to test when the application is a bit more robust. This specific set up is still in it's infancy.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you posted translates to this:

```
PERMISSIONS.Where(p =>
  PERMISSION_GROUP_REF.Where(pg =>
    GROUPS.Where(g =>
      GROUP_USER_REF.Where(gu => gu.USER_ID == USERID)
                    .Any(gu => gu.GROUP_ID == g.ID))
          .Any(g => g.ID == pg.GROUP_ID))
        .Any(pg => pg.PERMISSION_ID == p.ID))
```

Maybe you can simplify it a bit, but this should work.

Comment: Tidied the formatting a bit so I can read it, hope you don't mind

Comment: I edited it in to the original question, but I should have specified before: I'm using Entity Framework 6, so there doesn't actually exist classes / models of the reference objects (PERMISSION_GROUP_REF and GROUP_USER_REF).